# Modification to STL List Contents in C++

Tags: c++, stl

In the below Code-snippet, I am trying to manipulate the contents of each of the lists present in the MAP mp but by returning a pointer to list corresponding map's key whose list needs modification. I am aware that a direct modification of the list contents is possible instead of calling getlist and then modifiying it, but I am new to STL and C++ and trying to learn STL by playing around a bit with Iterators and Lists.

When the below code is executed, a Segmentation fault is thrown at the line "(*lit) = 10". Can anyone help me understand what's going wrong here?

```
static void getlist(int num,map<int,list<int>> mp, list<int>** l_ptr )
{
    map<int,list<int>>::iterator it = mp.begin();
    while( it != mp.end())
    {
        if(it->first == num )
        {
            *l_ptr = &(it->second);
            return;
        }
        it++;
    }

}

int main() 
{
    map<int,list<int>> mp;
    mp[1] = {2,2,2};
    mp[2] = {3,3,3};
    mp[3] = {4,4,4};
    map<int,list<int>>::iterator it = mp.begin();
    list<int>::iterator lit;
    list<int>* r_l = new list<int>;

    //getlist(it->first,mp,r_l);
    while( it != mp.end())
    {
        getlist(it->first,mp,&r_l);
        lit = r_l->begin();
        while(lit != r_l->end())
        {
            (*lit) = 10;
            lit++;
        }
        it++;
    }

    it = mp.begin();
    while( it != mp.end())
    {
        lit = (it->second).begin();
        while(lit != (it->second).end())
        {
            cout<<(*lit);
            lit++;
        }
        it++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just use `list<int> &rl = it->second;` in `while` instead of calling your `getlist()`

Comment: `map<int,list<int>> mp,` in getlist is a copy.

Comment: You should post that as an answer. r_l is pointing to the copies argument, which goes out of scope